# if one observation meet criteria fill other with the same value for a new variable

Tags: r

I have data.frame like this

```
test <- data.frame(plot = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), sort = c(10, 20, 11, 12, 15, 20))
```

I want to create a new variable callled `treat` that will be `"A"` if any `sort` in the `plot` is `20`. Otherwise it should be `B`.
The expected output is

```
data.frame(plot = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), sort = c(10, 20, 11, 12, 15, 20), treat = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ave` and group by `plot` variable. Check if any `sort` variable has value as 20 in it and assign the group accordingly

```
test$treat<-ave(test$sort,test$plot,FUN =function(x) ifelse(any(x ==20),"A","B"))
test

#   plot sort treat
#1    1   10     A
#2    1   20     A
#3    2   11     B
#4    2   12     B
#5    3   15     A
#6    3   20     A
```

---

Similary with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
  group_by(plot) %>%
  mutate(treat = ifelse(any(sort ==  20), "A", "B"))
```

Comment: Thx, I have not known the function `any`